# How to cache whole pages using nginx?

Tags: caching, proxies

Currently I am using nginx and php5-fpm behind Varnish to render pages. It is great of guest users; however, I feel it is a bit slow and [error-prone](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23163/error-503-service-unavailable) for authenticated users, and I'd like to disable Varnish and use nginx built-in cache, to cache the whole content for, say, one minute. I could not find a working sample of nginx mysite.conf for drupal 6 to do so. I would appreciate if you paste one here.

I would also like to hear your experience/benchmarks of nginx cache versus Varnish.

Comment: This seems out of place.  Migration to [sf] perhaps?

Comment: Well, I think it is a Drupal-specific question. I want a working nginx config to do the caching

Comment: You want a working nginx (server) caching configuration.  I don't understand why this wouldn't be more at home on [sf].

Comment: Chapabu, by your argument, all the web-server specific questions of the community should be moved over to serverfault. I don't see the point though.

Comment: All web-server specific question should be moved to the web-server specific Stack Exchange.  They are still listed here albeit with a [migrated] tag, and you'll get answers from server professionals.  Where's the issue here?

Comment: Well they may be more server professions at serverfault, but certainly here are also 'professions' whit hands-on experience who can give more pertinent answers. People come here to get answer for their drupal problems, including server-related ones so I see the dichotomy between drupal-server-specific and drupal-not-server-specific rather superficial and probably unhelpful. In addition, consider that searching drupal-specific answers elsewhere would be more difficult, unless we add 'drupal' tag to each and every of the migrated question.

Comment: Please read:  **Your question will still be accessible from here**.  It will just be migrated to a place where it may get more attention and more in depth assistance.  If a user has an account here, they can also log in at [sf] if they have an answer.  I have obviously overstepped the mark, and I apologise for attempting to get you suitable answers to your query.

Comment: If nginx requires a specific configuration for working better with Drupal, then the question is on-topic here; if there isn't anything specific that needs to be set for Drupal, then the question is off-topic. The question is: Does the answer change, removing Drupal from the equation? If it changes, then the question is on-topic here.